# Ubuntu-20.04 [ end Kernel panic = not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 ]

Tags: 20.04, kernel, java

First, I will upload a picture right after the kernel panic appears.

[image]

This symptom occurred after upgrading to Java 1.10 while using Java 1.8 and rebooting.

Is there a way to access it somehow and delete Java?
Even if it is not a method of deleting Java, it is possible to transfer to the OS by another method.
I would like to know if there is a way.

Thank you for your interest.